# Where are memory management algorithms used?

Tags: algorithm, memory-management

There are a set of memory management algorithms used in operating system construction, like pagination, segmentation, paged segmentation (paginación segmentada), segment pagination (segmentación paginada) and others.

Do you know if they are used besides that area, in not so low level software? They are used in bussiness applications?

Comment: can you explain why you downvoted this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These algoritms are for translating the program memory addresses onto the physical memory addresses. You will very rarely ever have to think of it in an application. In some extreme cases of applications working on very large datasets you may have to create a driver-like module to tune memory translation, but all the rest is still up to the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You might never write an OS yourself, but if you ever find yourself having to write a device driver, it will be imperitive that you understand these issues. So it is still quite useful to understand how these algorithms work.

Now you might be in school thinking, "Yuck, I'll just avoid that stuff". But you really have no idea where a 40-year carreer in the industry might take you.